# Showing there are no nontrivial ring homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-writing

I have:

If $\phi:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ is a homomorphism, then $f(1)=f(1\ast1)=f(1)\cdot f(1)$. Then $$0=f(1)\cdot f(1)-f(1)=f(1)\cdot\left[f(1)-\epsilon\right]$$ implies that $f(1)=0$ or $f(1)=1$, since there are no zero-divisors in $\mathbb{Z}$.

How should I show that this leads to the fact that $\forall x\in\mathbb{Z}$, we have $f(x)=0$ or $f(x)=x$?

Comment: There are lots of homomorphisms, if you consider $\mathbb Z$ as a group. Please state that you are asking about *ring* homomorphism.

Comment: If you know $\phi(1)$, then you know $\phi(2) = \phi(1+1) = \phi(1)+\phi(1)$, and $\phi(3) = \phi(2+1) = \phi(2)+\phi(1)$, and so on...

Comment: If $f(1) = 0$, then $f$ is trivial. If $f(1) = 1$, then $f = \text{id}_{\Bbb Z}$....why? Because $1$ generates $\Bbb Z$ as a ring (it is a *cyclic ring*).

Comment: For $x \geq 1$, prove it by induction on $x$. For $x < 0$, then use $f(x) + f(-x) = f(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\bullet f(0)=f(0+0)=f(0)+f(0)\implies f(0)=0.$$  $$\bullet f(1)=f(1^2)=f(1)^2\implies (f(1)=1\lor f(1)=0).$$  $$ \bullet f(1)=0\implies \forall n\;(f(n)=f(1\cdot n)=f(1)f(n)=0\cdot f(n)=0).$$  $$\bullet f(1)=1\implies \forall n\in N \; (f(n)=n\implies f(n+1)=f(n)+f(1)=n+1).$$ So by induction on $n\in N$ we have $$f(1)=1\implies \forall n\in N\;(f(n)=n).$$ $$\text {Now we have }\;(\forall n\in N \;(f(n)=n)\implies$$ $$\implies (\forall n\in N \;(0=f(0)=f(n+(-n))=f(n)+f(-n)=n+f(-n))\implies$$ $$\implies  (\forall n\in N\;(f(-n)=-n).$$  Therefore  $\quad \bullet f(1)=1\implies \forall n\;(f(n)=n)$.